# I can generate access tokens for Gmail API but they don't work

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I need to access my emails with Gmail API. My app worked well, but suddenly stops working for one of my email address since I made some changes on my account:

I Activate 2 steps authentification for my google account and link another email address to my mailbox. I can still generate some access tokens with my client ID, client secret and refresh token, but then when I make an HTTP request with these access tokens, I get a 401 Invalid credentials error.

I have already tried to generate new credentials (client ID, client secret, refresh token and API key) with some different scopes but same problem.

I have also tried to make the same changes (Activate 2 steps authentification and link another email address to my mailbox) on another google account I have, and it is still working with this other account, so I don't know if this is the source of my problem

Every hour my app send this HTTP request :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

returns :

```
{'access_token': 'ya29.GluBBwcGyd2mVgyUtHLUX36caQjnznp_rohsOP3thhEJXYMdF1Z0ElUa5V1AXv1kULguOfq4tR4KApSkYhQYimmnT3Nhw4F_nSXlOVyHZRKchr_qObYd1R80qaQo', 'expires_in': 3600, 'scope': 'https://mail.google.com/ , 'token_type': 'Bearer'}
```

Then I get an error on every requests like this :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{my-email-adress}/messages?key={my-api-key}
Authorization: Bearer {my-access-token}
```

returns :

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'authError', 'message': 'Invalid Credentials', 'locationType': 'header', 'location': 'Authorization'}], 'code': 401, 'message': 'Invalid Credentials'}}
```

Any idea how to fix it?
If you need more information just tell me

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: try  https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages  instead and let me know what happends

Comment: Have you tried unlinking the second account and linking it again? Have you tried with this scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly ?

Comment: Hello DalmTo and Andres and thank you for your replies ! I have tried to replace user_id by "me", unlink the second account, generate some new credentials with only the scope googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly, but same problem :/ Any other ideas ?

Comment: Could you please provide the entire code involved?